# post-increment and assignment in an array index

Tags: c

I have encountered a terse piece of code which I am finding very difficult to decipher.

```
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
{
    C[p=w[T[k]]++] = Y1[k];
    CC[p] = Y2[k]
}
```

w and T look like this:

```
w = [0 3 6 8]
T = [2 0 3 2 1 0 1 3 0 1]
```

I am unable to figure what is the index that the array `C` and `CC` are going to get when k = 0 and a way to read the code easily.

This is what I had tried to do.

When

```
k = 0,
T[0] = 2,
w[2] = 6
p = 6
w[2] = 7
c[6] and cc[6] are assigned
```

Comment: "Split" *that* statement into multiple statements, separating nested indexing and it'll become clear.

Comment: @P.P. I tried that but I was getting wrong answer. I got the the index as 6 and 6 but the correct value is 7.

Comment: @Morpheus Well, post whatever you have done so that others can verify or point out what's wrong with it. Besides this sort of "clever" code doesn't have much practical purpose.

Comment: If I remember correctly this is undefined behavior, where increment might take place after reading in memory.

Comment: @GRC No undefined behavior here as far as I can see.

Comment: @EugeneSh. this is not the case like when you increment the value inside function call? In that case, value might be passed before it was incremented or might not be (ie. if `i = 0`  `int printInt(++i)` might print `0` or `1`) depending on machine/compiler

Comment: @GRC Even in your example it is well defined. It will always print `1`.  All of the parameters are evaluated before the function call. And the function call is a sequence point. The UB will be if `i` is modified twice without the sequence point in between.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do not agree with you because look at this example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++

Comment: @GRC Which one of them?

Comment: @GRC - The wiki is a bit old and talks about C++11. The C++17 standard uses the example `i = i++ + 1;` as something that now works.

Comment: You never should write unreadable code like this anyway.

Comment: Find the person that wrote this code and shoot them.  Or, if that's against your morals or illegal where you live, throw rotten tomatoes at them instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the last one.

Comment: @GRC Note that `n` is referred twice there. The `n` is getting a side effect and is both modified and read without a sequence point in between. Which is not the case with your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it. This code is equivalent to:

```
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
{
    p = w[T[k]]++;
    C[p] = Y1[k];
    CC[p] = Y2[k]
}
```

which is the same as

```
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
{
    p = w[T[k]];   // For k=0 => w[2]=6 => p=6
    w[T[k]]++;     // For k=0 => increment w[2], so w[2] is 7
    C[p] = Y1[k];  // C[6] = Y1[0]
    CC[p] = Y2[k]  // CC[6] = Y2[0]
}
```